# Login loop with fresh 19.10 install

Tags: login, login-screen, 19.10

So I installed 19.10 fresh from USB. 
I picked no login required. 
First reboot after install I'm welcomed inside Ubuntu. 
But second time I'm prompted to login for no reason. 
Worst part is that i login with right password and all but it just loops me back to the login screen again. 
If I enter wrong password, it tells me I'm wrong. 
Tried to login via terminal and then type "sudo startx".
That just led me back to login screen.

Please help me, I'm running a first gen amd ryzen and nvidia 980ti.

Edit:
**SOLVED!** In my answer below.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135110/login-loop-after-upgrading-to-19-04.

Comment: Early ryzen processors were recalled due to a Linux compatibility problem. Users were given a free replacement. Google it and see if yours is one of those. Also, did you use `sudo` in the `terminal`?

Comment: Hum that bug seems like a more the possible reason. I might try the test tomorrow.

Comment: Add your answer to a new post (you can reply to your own post, just look at the end of the page), and mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### SOLVED

That's a problem related to the NVIDIA Kernel Module failing with proprietary drivers. To solve it, do the following steps:

- At the login screen, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>  to enter the terminal and login with your name
  and password
- Type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` (you can change `nano` to the text
  editor of your preference)
  to edit `/etc/default/grub`
- Change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to
  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"`
- Save the edition pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and exit pressing
  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>
- Update this grub edit with `sudo update-grub`
- Install lightdm using `sudo apt-get install lightdm`
- Reboot typing `sudo reboot`

Comment: (1) Should it be "nomodset" or "nomodeset" ?
(2) Nano write-out command is ^o not ^c. 
(3) Can't install lightdm, as there is no network in recovery terminal mode.

Answer (score 11):

I had this issue after upgrading from 19.04 to 19.10.

The solution that worked for me is to switch display manager from GDM3 to LightDM.

If you have installed the `lightdm` package, just run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` and select LightDM.

After rebooting you should be able to log in.

**I have since found a solution to fix login loop without changing GDM3 to LightDM:**

1. On the login screen, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.
2. Log in to the shell using your username and password.
3. Uninstall and reinstall the `gdm3` package:

   ```bash
   sudo apt-get purge gdm3
   sudo apt-get install gdm3
   ```

Now just select GDM3, and after a reboot it should work fine.

Comment: This got me going again (updated solution) thanks heaps!

Comment: [`apt` > `apt-get`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445384/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-and-apt-get)

Comment: Solved my issue as well on a clean install

Comment: First suggestion worked for me, second suggestion did not

Comment: Far from a clean install, but the second solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to boot in recovery mode (if grub does not show a menu hold shift key while booting). And then remove a gnome shell extension as explained in this answer :

[Login loop after upgrading to 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1135250/637053)

if it does not work, in grub menu press e key to edit boot menu option add nomodeset as kernel parameter at the end of the line which has "Linux" in it.

```
Linux /boot/vmlinuz... nomodeset
```

press Ctrl+x to boot.

Comment: Tyvm for your answer. But I'm about to give up. I tried to ctrl + alt + f2 my way into the grub config. Tried to sudo vi /etc/default/grub and change GRUB_TIMEOUT=10 and - 1 but it seems like I can't get inte to grub menu. Changed GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden to GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu without any success. Tried to press shift, f1 and esc after bios. Esc gives me grub bash. But that's not what I want. Also I tried to uninstall those gnome packages and that did not work either.

Comment: @Huux Did you run `update-grub` after editing `/etc/default/grub`?

Comment: @jake thank you, missed to do that!

Comment: So it seems like grub does not save the nomodset addition at boot. But I finally found a workaround and I will say that gerdiz answer helped me towards that solution!

Answer (score 0):

After installing lightdm display manager and rebooting, I was able to login just fine.

```
 sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

**System Specifics:**

```
OS: Ubuntu 19.10,  Kernel: 5.3.0-19-generic
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU104 [GeForce RTX 2080 Rev. A]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
Display Manager: Gnome Display Manager (GDM)
Driver: nvidia-driver-435
```