# Partial upgrade from 20.04 LTS to 20.10

Tags: partial-upgrade, 20.10

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to Ubuntu 20.10 but due to Partial Upgrade my screen is showing

"Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occured and the system can't recover"

I referred below answer but when I pressed ctrl+Alt+F3.
Blinking screen pops up instead of login screen

Please help me resolve this!
Thanks in advance!

[Login loop on Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183210/login-loop-on-ubuntu-19-10)