# Ubuntu 19.10 Login Loop After Installing Proprietary Nvidia Drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login, gdm, 19.10

**Background**

After installing Nvidia proprietary driver (nvidia-driver-435), got caught in a login loop (see below for system specifics).  After typing in my password and pressing enter my desktop display did not appear rather it kicked me back to the login screen as if nothing had happened.  Question is how do I fix this problem so I can log in normally?

**System Specifics:**

```
OS: Ubuntu 19.10,  Kernel: 5.3.0-19-generic
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU104 [GeForce RTX 2080 Rev. A]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
Display Manager: Gnome Display Manager (GDM)
```

**FIX:**

See below and also this thread:

[Login loop with fresh 19.10 install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182506/login-loop-with-fresh-19-10-install)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login loop with fresh 19.10 install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182506/login-loop-with-fresh-19-10-install)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fix**

The problem was with GDM display manager and the Nvidia driver, seems they still do not play well together even in 19.10.  I wasn't able to determine the root cause of the problem, however what worked for me was to install lightdm and change the grub command line on startup.

```
On the login screen press:
• Ctrl + Alt + F2 to enter the terminal and log in.
• Edit /etc/default/grub. I did it with sudo <yourtexteditor> /etc/default/grub.
• Change the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodset".
• Update this grub edit with update grub (tyvm @jake).
sudo apt-get install lightdm
• reboot
```

After installation, I was able to login as normal with the NVIDIA driver installed (nvidia-driver-435).

Reference: [Login loop with fresh 19.10 install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182506/login-loop-with-fresh-19-10-install)

Comment: Just remove the splash from the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"  This resolves the issue for 19.10 and also for 20.04