# After upgrade to 19.10, still get login screen after enabling Auto Login, but can't log in

Tags: upgrade, login, 19.04, 19.10

The following started after upgrading from 19.04 to 19.10 using LiveUSB.

After enabling Auto Login for my user account, I still get a login screen, and entering my password just knocks me back to the login screen.

Going into terminal mode and editing /etc/gdm3/custom.conf to disable auto login allows me to login normally again:

```
<ctrl>-<alt>-F2
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

ensure AutomaticLoginEnable is set to 'False' and uncommented:

```
AutomaticLoginEnable=False
```

What could be causing this issue with Auto Login?

Comment: i have same issue. have you reported the bug to ubuntu? probably you should. i don't think your question "What could be causing this issue?" has some other answer than just "it's a bug, the bug causes this issue"

Comment: not only i had this bug after upgrading from live usb - after that, i completely reinstalled ubuntu (formatted original partition and installed a fresh ubuntu on it) - and again, had the same issue - thank to your post - i found the solution here!

Answer (score 0):

yup, as i said in comments earlier, the answer to your question "what could be causing this issue?" - is: "the following bug is causing it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1845801 "

please vote the bug report up and subscribe for notifications - this increases its "hotness" - maybe they'll fix it faster?