# After installing both 18.04.3 and 19.10, stuck at login, returned to login screen

Tags: drivers, nvidia, system-installation

I bought a computer a couple of months ago wasn't able to make it work so tried again, here is the spec:

- CPU:          Intel Core i7 9700K
- Motherboard : [Gigabyte Z390 UD](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/Z390-UD-rev-10#kf)
- SSD:          Samsung SSD 1.0TB 970 EVO Plus NVMe M.2
- GPU:          [palit geforce rtx 2070](http://www.palit.com/palit/vgapro.php?id=3020&lang=en&pn=NE62070S1AP2-1062A&tab=do)

When trying to install I got these error messages:

- nouveau : unknown chipset
- PCIE bus error: severity=corrected, type physical layer

After installing I was able to reach the login screen, when I move my mouse over my user name to log in, mouse movements are choppy. and after i enter password (also choppy typing) I return to the login screen.

I've spent a lot of hours on this and no success.

Edit:

- tried to install for desktop 18.04.03 and 19.10
- I didn't enable HWE, just downloaded from the official website created ISO and tried to  install

  - How do I enable HWE?

How do I make it work?

Comment: What release or flavor of Ubuntu did you try?  Exact details are requested, eg. if Ubuntu 18.04 LTS was HWE enabled?  (ie. 18.04.2 or 18.04.3) or did you use desktop ISO? server ISO? or other?

Comment: @guiverc Added an edit, tried to install 18.04.03 and 19.10. no HWE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: The Gigabyte motherboard has no Linux driver support: Windows 10 drivers only per https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/Z390-UD-rev-10#kf . Likewise, your video card manufacturer provides no Linux drivers; see http://www.palit.com/palit/vgapro.php?id=3020&lang=en&pn=NE62070S1AP2-1062A&tab=do

Comment: @K7AAY this is from Gigabyte link you provided: **Due to different Linux support condition provided by chipset vendors, please download Linux driver from chipset vendors' website or 3rd party website.**

It doesn't say no linux support just that you need to download myself, maybe there are packages that already provide it?

Comment: fyi:  18.04.3 does have HWE enabled; but by providing the 18.04**.3** this detail is provided. There were nvidia drivers provided on the day 19.10 was released (but hours after release), meaning support isn't on the ISO but I forget the detail of which cards or support...

Comment: @user4602966 Having iinstalled Ubuntu on dozens of the Gigabyte Z390, nope.

Comment: @K7AAY I see now, so I'm screwed

Comment: Checking to see if components support Ubuntu or Debian before buying is a Good Thing. But, since I have installed 18.04.3 on many of these, without needing any special drivers, I think the issue is with the video adapter and not the motherboard. If you were my brother-in-law, I would suggest you remove the video card and install without it, then try to troubleshoot the video card ssue.

Comment: You might need a specific or updated nvidia driver. Have you tried `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`? If your graphic chipset is RTX 2070, I don't think the manufacturer matters that much. You don't necessarily need to go to Palit (or whatever) to get the graphics drivers. You don't need a chipset driver either, Z390 is supported in all the recent kernels. All you really need is a working graphics driver, and there are plenty of alternatives to `nouveau`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login loop with fresh 19.10 install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182506/login-loop-with-fresh-19-10-install)

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me, that's a problem related to the NVIDIA Kernel Module failing with proprietary drivers. To solve it, do the following steps:

- At the login screen, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> and login with your name
  and password
- Type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` (you can change `nano` to the text
  editor of your preference, but nano is Ubuntu's default text editor)
  to edit `/etc/default/grub`
- Change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to
  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodset"`
- Update this grub edit with `update grub`
- Install lightdm using `sudo apt-get install lightdm`
- Reboot (you can shutdown throught the terminal with `shutdown now`)

Comment: `lightdm`? This is 19.10, there is no unity. `lightdm` has been replaced with `gdm3` since 2016.

Comment: Well, at least that was the solution that worked out for me (and also for other people). However, I can try the same solution, but without lightdm to see if it still works.