# After login, black screen for 30 seconds and then enter the system

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, system-installation

I had this issue previously: [After installing both 18.04.3 and 19.10, stuck at login, returned to login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193895/after-installing-both-18-04-3-and-19-10-stuck-at-login-returned-to-login-scree?noredirect=1#comment1999011_1193895)

After some more tries I was able to install Ubuntu 19.10, but I am not sure exactly what was different.

Now when I reach the login screen, I enter my password and the screen goes black for 30 seconds, and afterwards I'm able to use Ubuntu.

I have installed the Nvidia 435 driver using Software & Update.

Checking the video card with `lspci |grep VGA`, I see:

```
VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 [Geforce RTX 2070] (rev a1)
```

Checking `syslog` and `kern.log`, I see

```
PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer
```

repeating a lot.

How can I fix the error and the slow loading? Is there anything else I need to take care of?

Changing display settings makes the system to freeze for 30 seconds and then it continues to work.

Shutting down was OK before, but now it sees the error repeating, and it won't stop. The computer keeps outputting this error and won't shut down.