# hard disk memory being used extremely quickly

Tags: partitioning, ssd

Installed 19.10 recently.

I have another issue opened, maybe it's related: [After login, black screen for 30 sec than enter the system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194004/after-login-black-screen-for-30-sec-than-enter-the-system)

Have Error: `PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer`

checked partition size being used with GParted: **260G** being used out of 930

this didn't make sense to me, tried to delete syslog and kern.log.
Swap file is 2G, a mistake in reading.

checked GParted: **264G** used

This happened in less than a min.

Shutting down and restart seems to clear the memory being used, but it's starting to use memory again **32G** and less than 20 sec **33G**

- How can i check what is eating the SSD?
- What can I do if my SSD memory is out?

Comment: Your hard disk *storage* is being consumed. *Memory* usually refers to RAM. *Storage* usually refers to (mountable devices like) disk/SSD/memory-card space. Using the wrong term confuses everybody.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out whats eating my SSD, it's the reports, seems deleting isn't enough. so I shut down rsyslog service and it solved the problem.

Comment: This does not solve the real problem. The reason for the logs filling up is a hardware or driver problem. By stopping the logging you risk that other importent errors don't get logged, and you don't have a chance to work out what are going wrong. Search for the real problem and fix it !!

Comment: @SorenA there is another submission about the error that is being reported. I'm stopping the service until I solve the other issue

Comment: That's okay, but please post it as a solution to the problem. It could mislead others that don't have the whole story.

Comment: @user4602966  Stopping rsyslog is the absolute wrong thing to do. Find out what's filling syslog, and fix it. Try `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog` and look for repeating entries.