# How to stop popup asking to authenticate for everything

Tags: login, lightdm, authentication

Ever since installing lightdm to fix the login password loop issue, I receive a popup asking me to authenticate from everything to wifi scans, to color profile, to refresh system repositories. I've tried dozens of different guides, advice, and nothing seems to work.

This problem started when I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182506/login-loop-with-fresh-19-10-install) answer and changed my /etc/default/grub file by modifying the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` from "quite splash" to "nomodset", then installed lightdm. I reverted it back to it's default value of `quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor`. I also tried changing the permissions of the .Xauthority file, but that didn't work. Also, my brightness buttons seems to be screwed up in that I have to hold them for very long before I notice the brightness changing.

I just want to stop the popup that asks me to authenticate for everything, and am hoping the community here has some advice.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what OS/release you are running, but I can't imagine why switching from *unspecified*dm to `lightdm` would be helpful anyway using standard repository software.... ie. there are holes possibly you should fill to your question that may help get useful answers.

Comment: Sorry, I'm in 19.10. I don't know what else would be helpful, but can provide whatever anyone asks for. All I know is the problem started as soon as I installed lightdm and changed the /etc/default/grub file.