# Login loop after host rename using hostnamectl

Tags: login, 19.10, auto-login

I renamed my host with

```
hostnamectl set-hostname 'new-hostname'
```

Now I am stuck in a login loop and can only access my computer with the recovery mode.

I searched around and everybody is says that it has to to something to do with .Xauthority like here.

[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

But I don't even have that folder.

I am running Ubuntu 19.10.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

This answer solved my problem:

[Login loop with fresh 19.10 install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182506/login-loop-with-fresh-19-10-install)