# Sudo is not running Command not found error Login Loop on UBUNTU 19.10

Tags: command-line, login, 19.10, system, system-settings

I tried all the ways that are given on previous ask@ubuntu but my problem is such different
after pressing `alt+ctrl+F2` and login to `user` I tried to run all commands given but it gave me

error

error is `the command is not located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.`

> sudo command not found
>   even sudo is not working

Comment: Easy solution: Backup your data and reinstall.

Comment: Does it work if you use the full path i.e. `/usr/bin/sudo somecommand` ?

Comment: `-bash: /usr/bin is a directory` it give me this

Answer (score 1):

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"
```

That should do the trick for the session

Answer (score 0):

[I used the answer of this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182506/login-loop-with-fresh-19-10-install)

but on after installing `lightdm` (lightdm works perfectly) it's still on loop and doesn't allow me to login to my UBUNTU

please suggest me something.