# Ubuntu 22.04 won’t let put the password

Tags: 22.04, password, freeze, login-screen

I upgraded ubuntu to version 22.04 just today, when it finshed the upgrade, it restarted the machine, however since then when boots and gets to login screen, I can see my username but it won’t move so I can enter the password, it is just stuck there, how do I fix this, and what might be the reason for this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: You didn't mention if you're asking about Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server, or Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop.  A desktop or GUI system won't allow logins if free disk space is insufficient (in $HOME) but text logins will proceed, so switch to text terminal & check. You mention an upgrade, but not from what? I'd ensure system is fully upgraded whilst at terminal & look around, but if GUI extensions you added can may also not work in newer version... there are many possible causes.  You tagged freeze?  What do you mean by that?  Does the mouse freeze & nothing is responsive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Login loop after upgrading to 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135110/login-loop-after-upgrading-to-19-04)